# Communication between a Web App and a Desktop Application

Tags: web-applications, progressive-web-apps, executable, desktop-application

I am looking at a scenario to establish communication between a Web App and a Desktop Application.

The Web App is built on react.
The Desktop application is an executable that provides web user the access to local resources such as printing, file system access, registry access etc.

We have tried and tested the option of a built in local Web Server embedded in the Desktop application. This however have given rise to many limitations for us. Hence we are now looking at other secure means of communicating between the Web App and the Desktop application.

Some other approaches that were considered are:
1.Direct communication with the Web server
2.USe of custom protocol handler
3.Progressive Web App interface

Both options (1) and (2) are contenders with their plus points and negatives.

I am trying to find an answer to:

- Can a Progressive Web App be used for this purpose? Can a PWA talk to an executable..?
- Are there other solutions that can be considered for the above requirement..?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using native messaging for browser communication with a desktop application.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging

Messages from the browser will be passed along to your native messaging host which can then forward them along to your desktop application and vice-versa.

You can communicate directly from the browser if you're desktop application runs a local web server as you mentioned, but your experience will vary with different browsers and will probably give you more problems than it's worth.

Comment: The links points to chrome apps docs, which are discontinues. The API seems to be valid chrome extensions: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/nativeMessaging/